# Loop stops after reaching Email.send line without any error

Tags: excel, vba

I made a code, to send multiple emails based on a manual selection.
My problem is that when I'm reaching the .send email, the code does not go to the next "For" value. It sends the email, the loop stops, and the code starts from the beginning without following my For instruction anymore.

Here is my code:

```
Sub MailTenders()
' add ref - tool -> references - > Microsoft Outlook XX.X Object Library
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application


    Dim Email As Outlook.MailItem


' add ref - tool -> references - > Microsoft Word XX.X Object Library
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document '<=========


    Dim tempWB As Workbook
    Set tempWB = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim sht As Excel.Worksheet
    Set sht = tempWB.Sheets("Email")

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = sht.Range("A1:N22").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        'rng.Copy

    Dim reg As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim com As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim edata As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lstrow As Range
    Dim lastr_nr As Long
    Dim lastc_nr As Long

    Set reg = tempWB.Sheets("Register")
    Set com = tempWB.Sheets("Companies")
    Set edata = tempWB.Sheets("Email Data")

    Dim iCounter As Integer
    Dim usermail As String
    Dim compny As String
    Dim atchm As String
    Dim emailrng As Range, cl As Range
    Dim sto As String
    Dim lc As Integer


    com.Activate
    lc = Application.CountA(com.Range("A:A"))

    For iCounter = 2 To lc 'WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(1))
            If Cells(iCounter, 6).Value = "x" Then

    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set Email = olApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set wdDoc = Email.GetInspector.WordEditor

    usermail = Cells(iCounter, 5).Value
    compny = Cells(iCounter, 2).Value
    atchm = Cells(iCounter, 4).Value

                reg.Activate
                Range("A1").Select
                Selection.End(xlDown).Select
                Set lstrow = ActiveCell 
                lastr_nr = ActiveCell.Row   
                Range("a" & lastr_nr + 1).Value = Range("a" & lastr_nr) + 1
                Range("b" & lastr_nr + 1).Select
                ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=NOW()"
                ActiveCell.Copy
                ActiveCell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
                Range("c" & lastr_nr + 1).Value = compny
                Range("d" & lastr_nr + 1).Value = atchm

                edata.Activate
                Range("B9").Select
                Set emailrng = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight))
                lastc_nr = ActiveCell.Column
                sto = ""
                For Each cl In emailrng
                sto = sto & ";" & cl.Value
                Next
                sto = Mid(sto, 2)

                com.Activate




    rng.Copy

        With Email
        .To = usermail
        .CC = sto
        .Subject = "Cerere oferta pentru proiectul " & edata.Range("B1").Value
        wdDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatOriginalFormatting
'        .Display
        .Attachments.Add "c:\Users\HorbaniucVla\OneDrive - Strabag BRVZ GmbH\BL 2019\CJV Vintu - Simeria\14. Tenders\02. CP\Atasamente\" & atchm & ".zip"
        .SaveAs "c:\Users\HorbaniucVla\OneDrive - Strabag BRVZ GmbH\BL 2019\CJV Vintu - Simeria\14. Tenders\02. CP\Offers Sent\" & edata.Range("b10") & ".msg", OlSaveAsType.olMsg
        .send '!!!Here the code stops after sending the first email !!!
        End With

     reg.Activate
     Range("e" & lastr_nr + 1).Select
     Range("e" & lastr_nr + 1).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="c:\Users\HorbaniucVla\OneDrive - Strabag BRVZ GmbH\BL 2019\CJV Vintu - Simeria\14. Tenders\02. CP\Offers Sent\" & edata.Range("b10") & ".msg", TextToDisplay:="draft email link"
     Range("f" & lastr_nr + 1).Select
     Range("e" & lastr_nr + 1).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="c:\Users\HorbaniucVla\OneDrive - Strabag BRVZ GmbH\BL 2019\CJV Vintu - Simeria\14. Tenders\02. CP\Atasamente\" & atchm & ".zip", TextToDisplay:="attachement link"
    End If
    Next iCounter

End Sub
```

For a better understanding, I also made a GIF with the code step into which unfortunately it is bigger than 2mb and I will share [via dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g3hdkcdppbq4t4m/2019-09-11_16-54-08.gif?dl=0).
The GIF is animated, but I noticed is not working without download.

Comment: Hello, I solved it. It was a stupid thing.  

 For iCounter = 2 To lc 'WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(1))
     com.Activate
            If Cells(iCounter, 6).Value = "x" Then